# Equivalent property of a positiv definite operator

Tags: functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, hilbert-spaces

I'm looking at the following problem:

> Let $H$ be a Hilbertspace over $\mathbb{K}, T\neq 0$ be a compact, self-adjoint operator with orthonormalsystem $(e_i)_{i\in J}$ of eigenvectors to eigenvalues $(\lambda_i)_{i\in J}\subset \mathbb{K}\backslash\{0\}, J\subset \mathbb{N}$. Then:
>
> $( x,Tx)_H>0\quad \forall x\in H\backslash\{0\}$
>
> $\Leftrightarrow\lambda_i\geq 0\quad \forall i\in J$ and $(e_i)_{i\in J}$ is a Schauder-basis.

I already got "$\Leftarrow$", so what's left to show is "$\Rightarrow$". For that part, I already got that $(x,Tx)\geq 0\quad \forall x\in H\backslash\{0\}\Leftrightarrow\lambda_i\geq0 \quad \forall i\in J$, but I don't know how to show now that $(e_i)_{i\in J}$ is a Schauder-basis. Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's hard to answer this without context. What does "with orthonormal system  of eigenvectors mean". Usually that would already be a basis. If that's not what you are assuming, you should probably state so.

Comment: If $H$ is not separable, then you cannot have a compact selfadjoint operator $T$ for which $(x,Tx)_H > 0$ for all $x\ne 0$ because there can be at most a countable number of positive eigenvalues, and each of the eigenspaces is finite-dimensional.

Answer (score 1):

By spectral decomposition, we have for all $x$
$$
Tx = \sum_{i\in J} \lambda_i \langle x_i,e_i\rangle e_i
$$
and there exists uniquely determined $x_0\in \ker(T)$ such that
$$
x= x_0 + \sum_{i\in J} \langle x_i,e_i\rangle e_i
$$
Now, if $\langle x,Tx\rangle>0$ for all $x\ne0$, this implies $\ker(T)=\{0\}$, and 
$$
x= \sum_{i\in J} \langle x_i,e_i\rangle e_i
$$
for all $x$, hence $(e_i)$ is a Schauder basis. 
(In this case $H$ is separable. In non-separable space, $\ker(T)$ has to be non-separable, and $\langle x,Tx\rangle>0$ for all $x\ne0$ is impossible.)